# htaccess does not open file when requested

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

tell me what the problem is, let's say there is a file web/quberty/2.jpeg, I go to the link host/quberty/2.jpeg, the site produces 404, although the rule is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1
```

whole htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Since you are adding web directory/folder to all uris, then have it as your very first rule and keep it at very top of your htaccess rules file.

Also please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [L]
```

You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was no flag, here's a working htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```